# AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'tree_'

Tags: machine-learning, python

everyone. I'm a noob in data science and I'm building my first ML model. But I keep getting this error,

```
'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'tree_'
```

This is my code below.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/mog/Downloads/train_data.csv')

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 1)

df.model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
df.model.fit(x_train, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

print('Training score...', accuracy_score(y_train, df_model.predict(x_train)))
print('Test score...', accuracy_score(y_test, df_model.predict(x_test)))
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to estimate a classification metric for a regression model.

So, depending on your target you have two options:

1. If it is categorical you need to use `DecisionTreeClassifier` instead of `DecisionTreeRegressor`
2. If it is continuous, you need to change the metric `accuracy_score` for example for `r2_score`

I also noticed you named your model `df.model` but when predicting this is named `df_model`. So I recommend to change both to `df_model`

Hope it helps!

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you!!!